# Is there value in taking a watered down version of a course like Index theory?

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry

So I am currently taking a watered-down version of a course on Index theory where the course doesn't require any differential geometry knowledge, only functional analysis is required. All the geometry is introduced along the way as needed. I was just wondering in general what people think about this and whether it is better to just learn all the prerequisites and then take the more hardcore version of the course that requires differential geometry and algebraic topology.

Comment: I actually do not understand how one can even formulate Index Theorem without some algebraic topology (one normally also needs vector bundles and characteristic classes). But all in all, there are no details here to make a suggestion one way or another (for instance, maybe at your place nobody is going to teach a "proper" index theory course).

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with taking at least two courses on the same topic. Taking a watered down version will prepare you well to learn the subject really well when you take the hardcore version.